# Apache ignite client not reconnect automatically after zookeeper server restart

Tags: spring, caching, apache-zookeeper, ignite, gridgain

I am running a single node Apache Ignite server with zookeeper discovery SPI mechanism using single node standalone zookeeper.

I am trying to connect the Ignite server from the client application using below discovery SPI configuration as below

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="zkConnectionString" value="127.0.0.1:2181"/>
        <property name="sessionTimeout" value="30000"/>
        <property name="zkRootPath" value="/apacheIgnite"/>
        <property name="joinTimeout" value="0"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

and zookeeper configurations as below

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
```

When ignite server stop and start then client application able to reconnect automatically since `joinTimeout` set as `0` this is fine,

But when zookeeper stop and start then client application couldn't able to reconnect automatically, it stopping with below log

`[stdout] (node-stopper) [14:07:16] Ignite node stopped OK`

please provide the configuration for the client to reconnect automatically after zookeeper restarts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are supposed to cycle stop and start Zk cluster. Zk is supposed to be resilient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if we take down the entire zookeeper cluster for maintenance or power down in the DC. In this case, do we have any option in ignite client to reconnect automatically without client restart?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I would assume that Ignite cluster is as durable as underlying Zk.